# iteration through pandas dataframes and numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, iteration

I am coming from a java background and new to numpy and pandas. 
I want to translate the following pseudo code into python.

```
theta[0...D] - numpy
input[1...D][0...N-1] - Pandas data frame
```

PSEUDO CODE:

```
mean = theta[0]
for(row = 0 to N-1)
     for(col = 1 to D)
          mean += theta[col] * input[row][col]
```

Implementation:

```
class simulator:
    theta = np.array([])
    stddev = 0

    def __init__(self, v_coefficents, v_stddev):
        self.theta = v_coefficents
        self.stddev = v_stddev

    def sim( self, input ):
        mean = self.theta[0]
        D = input.shape[0]
        N = input.shape[1]

        for index, row in input.iterrows():
            mean = self.theta[0]
            for i in range(D):
                mean += self.theta[i+1] *row['y']
```

I am concerned with iteration in the last line of code:
`mean += self.theta[i+1] *row['y']`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are working with NumPy, I would suggest extracting the pandas dataframe as an array and then we would have the luxury of working with `theta` and the extracted version of `input` both as arrays.

Thus, starting off we would have the array as -

```
input_arr = input.values
```

Then, the translation of the pseudo code would be -

```
mean = theta[0]
for row in range(N):
    for col in range(1,D+1):    
        mean += theta[col] * input_arr[row,col]
```

To perform the sum-reductions, with NumPy supporting vectorized operations and [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html), we would have the output with simply -

```
mean = theta[0] + (theta[1:D+1]*input_arr[:,1:D+1]).sum()
```

This could be optimized further with [`np.dot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) as a matrix-multiplication, like so -

```
mean = theta[0] + np.dot(input_arr[:,1:D+1], theta[1:D+1]).sum()
```

Please note that if you meant that `input` has a length of `D-1`, then we need few edits :

1. Loopy code would have : `input_arr[row,col-1]` instead of `input_arr[row,col]`.
2. Vectorized codes would have : `input_arr` instead of `input_arr[:,1:D+1]`.

Sample run based on [`comments`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41932321/iteration-through-pandas-dataframes-and-numpy/41932534?noredirect=1#comment71048451_41932534) -

```
In [71]: df = {'y' : [1,2,3,4,5]}
    ...: data_frame = pd.DataFrame(df)
    ...: test_coefficients = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
    ...: 

In [79]: input_arr = data_frame.values
    ...: theta = test_coefficients
    ...: 

In [80]: theta[0] + np.dot(input_arr[:,0], theta[1:])
Out[80]: 71
```

Comment: when I test theses values:
df = {'y' : [1,2,3,4,5]}
data_frame = pd.DataFrame(df)
test_coefficients = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])

 Error in sim
    mean += self.theta[col] * input_array[row, col]
IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1

Comment: @user I don't see how/where you are using `data_frame` and `test_coefficients` with my proposed codes. I am assuming those as the inputs.

Comment: within the sim method I convert the dataframe to numpy - input_arr, test_coefficients = theta

Comment: @user Just do : `np.dot(input_arr[:,0], theta[1:])`, where `input_arr = data_frame.values`. Posted a sample run. Check it out.